# kubectl get certificates : No resources found using cert-manager

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, cert-manager

I don't undestand why i can't get certificates on K8S using **cert-manager**

- I installed cert-manager : https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.7.1/cert-manager.crds.yaml
- I created ClusterIssuer

  ```
  apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
  kind: ClusterIssuer
  metadata:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
  spec:
    acme:
      email: user@example.com
      server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      privateKeySecretRef:
        name: example-issuer-account-key
      solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
  ```
- I created ingress

  ```
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
  spec:
    rules:
      - host: mytest.example.fr
        http:
          paths:
            - path: /
              pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: webapp
                  port:
                    number: 80
    tls:
      - hosts:
          - mytest.example.fr
        secretName: letsencrypt-staging
  ```

[image]

But when i try to get an certificate i get 'no resources found'
[image]

Any idea ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up your cluster? Did you use bare metal instalation or some cloud provider? Could you attach a yaml file of your ingress?

Comment: K8S version 1.22.2. I just copy my ingress on the post. Im using OVH provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create **kind certificate** you can use

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: cluster-issuer-name
  namespace: development
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: harsh@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: secret-name
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx-class-name
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-class-name
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: cluster-issuer-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sub.example.com
    http:
      .
      . #Path and service configs
      .
      .
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sub.example.com
    secretName: secret-name
```

**ingress** will call **clusterisser** and it will auto-create **certificate** for you.

Update **ingress** resources as per need if you are higher version **1.18** or **above**

**Notes**

- Make sure you are using the URL `https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` in clusterissue or else you will get **fake** certificate in browser.
- For refrence you can read more here :
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55183209/5525824
- Make sure also you ingress pointing to proper **clusterissuer** if
  you have created new.
- Also don't use same **privateKeySecretRef:name: secret-name** you
  need to delete it or use the **new** **name** as **fake certificate**
  now stored in that secret so.

Comment: I respect all your bullet point. but when i call `kubectl get certificates -A` i get **No resources found**

Comment: Check logs of cert manager and event of clusterissuer by describing resource

Comment: Thank you for your help you guided me to find my problem.
I installed by kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager.... (But no pod was created) So i install by Helm and now the pods (cert-manager pod) are well created and it works

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are not created automatically by cert-manager.
You have to create a YAML yourself. And use the issuer name that you have already created

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: my-certificate
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: set-a-new-name-here
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: mytest.example.fr
  dnsNames:
    - mytest.example.fr
```

Comment: Thank you, i created it but nothing change, on `kubectl describe certificate` I see the certificat but i always got Https error : *kubernetes ingress controller fake certificate*

Comment: No i switch with production `letsencrypt-prod` + `https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`